# Select other window in same frame using key shortcuts in elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

There are 2 windows open in the horizontally split Emacs frame. Now, using keyboard shortcut, i would like the input focus to shift to other window.

i think, `select-window` function does it programatically.

Comment: `C-x 5 o` calls the `other-frame` command, which changes focus to the next frame. You've also mentioned split windows, however, which doesn't seem relevant to the question, so I'm wondering if you're confusing windows and frames?

Comment: I agree with the previous comment that the question seems to confuse windows and frames. If you're in one frame containing two windows, you can use `C-x o`, which is bound to `other-window`, to go between them.

Comment: I edited the question, swapping "window" and "frame". It seems pretty clear that the OP mixed them up, but in a consistent way.

Comment: thanks @Drew for making the correction, though i could n't give credits for your edit.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `windmove` would help you. There are function like `windmove-left`, `windmove-right`, etc., and you can bind the key strokes you like to use the functions. For example, I set them up like the following:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-s-<left>") 'windmove-left)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-s-<right>") 'windmove-right)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-s-<up>") 'windmove-up)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-s-<down>") 'windmove-down)
```

With these settings, you can move the cursor between windows with arrow keys. You can change key stroke as you like.

http://emacswiki.org/emacs/WindMove

Answer (score 2):

If you're in one frame containing two windows, you can use `C-x o`, which is bound to `other-window`, to go between them.

Comment: And if the frame contains more than two windows then `C-x o` cycles among them.